# Hidden argument in JS function

Tags: javascript

There is the following code:

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0];
div.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(event);
});
```

Please, tell me, I don't pass 'event' argument to the event listener, I don't use 'this' - how does it work? I know about 'arguments' hidden function variable, but I don't know about this case. Maybe closure? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you don't pass event ?